# How i can divide a video in two parts (or more) with python?

Tags: python-3.x, video

I am developing a Youtube Download Bot in Telegram, the max size I can upload to Telegram is 50Mb, so some videos can't be upload because they are too big.

Is there any method to divide a video (for example: video.mp4 to video-1.mp4 and video-2.mp4)

I use python3.5.2 and python-telegram-bot to do the telegram bot, I also use youtube-dl to download the video.

Comment: I can recommend using [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) for the job (download the static build). You can execute `FFmpeg` from python, it's simpler using command line. You can also check here: [How can I use ffmpeg to split MPEG video into 10 minute chunks?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1670/how-can-i-use-ffmpeg-to-split-mpeg-video-into-10-minute-chunks)

Comment: Hi Welcome to StackOverflow aka. SO. I would recommend you provide any code you have written thus far and where you are having issues. Please see the help section as this will guide you in getting more support from us in the community. https://stackoverflow.com/help/ and make sure to avoid asking questions for opinion based or without code, as you will tend to get less support. https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and this is just a community feeling to not feel like we are completing someone’s homework. Best wishes on your endeavors! Cheers!

Comment: To add to @Rotem suggestion, there are pithing ffmpeg wrappers or binders you may want to look at also - e.g. https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python